# Find match in multiple line breaks

Tags: r, stringr

I need `KPRMILL` from the text below. Pattern is finding first `:` and a single space, then followed by desired text (till first line break `\n`)

```
x <- "\n        \n            NSE: KPRMILL\n        \n        \n            | \n            BSE: 532889\n        \n        \n        | INDUSTRY : TEXTILES\n        | SECTOR : TEXTILES, APPARELS & ACCESSORIES\n        "
```

I am able to solve this via combination of str_extract( ) and str_replace( ), looking for efficient solution.

```
x %>% str_extract("[.*?:]\\s+(.*?\\n)") %>% str_replace("(:\\s+)(.*)\\n","\\2")
```

Comment: Are you just looking for KPRMILL, not any of the other data points?

Comment: `x %>% str_extract("(?<=: )(.*)(?=\n)")` will extract the first of such patterns. I'm inferring you only care about the first, since there are four such patterns in that `x`. (If you want all four, use `str_extract_all` instead.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex [lookaround](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to find text before and/or after your pattern *without* including them in the returned text. `(?<=abc)qu+x` means *"find and return `qu+x` when it is preceded by `abc`"*; similarly, `qu+x(?=abc)` means *"find and return `qu+x` when it is followed by `abc`.

```r
str_extract(x, "(?<=: )(.*)(?=\n)")
# [1] "KPRMILL"
```

I'm inferring that you only want the first of the patterns in your `x`, since there are four. If you want the others, use `str_extract_all`:

```r
str_extract_all(x, "(?<=: )(.*)(?=\n)")
# [[1]]
# [1] "KPRMILL"                          "532889"                          
# [3] "TEXTILES"                         "TEXTILES, APPARELS & ACCESSORIES"
```